# gcloud auth application-default login runs into Access blocked error

Tags: google-oauth, gcloud, google-auth-library

Trying to execute `gcloud auth application-default login` yields one of these errors:

`Access blocked: Google Auth Library's request is invalid`

[image: Access blocked: Google Auth Library's request is invalid]

or

`Access blocked: Authorization Error`

[image: Access blocked: GAuthorization Error]

Comment: gcloud auth application-default login does not require any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update your gcloud version by running `gcloud components update` first.